# webView.loading always set to no

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am implementing a UIActivityIndicatorView to show that a UIWebView is loading. I have `if (_Annoucements.loading == YES) {
        [loadingSpinner startAnimating];
    }` to find out if it is loading or not. However this never has it start animating. And when I have `loadingSpinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES` the spinner never shows up at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know for a fact that `_Announcements.loading` is `NO`?  Did you set a breakpoint to confirm?

Answer (score 5):

Unless you're calling that `if` statement repeatedly, this won't accomplish what you want. `_Announcements.loading` just returns the current state.

What you want to do is set the delegate: `_Announcements.delegate = self` and use the following methods:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
   [loadingSpinner startAnimating];
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
   [loadingSpinner stopAnimating];
}
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
   [loadingSpinner stopAnimating];
}
```